# nodemon: permission denied while deploying on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, logging, permissions

[image]

I get the following error in my logs while deploying with Heroku, what can I do?

My `procfile`:

```
web: node bin/www
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "express-generator",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon.cmd  ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.29",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^6.0.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `nodemon` _at all_ on Heroku. That's a _development_ tool, not something that should be used in production. But what is `nodemon.cmd`? Is that a Windows thing? Heroku doesn't run Windows. Please [edit] your question and show us your `package.json` and, if you have one, your `Procfile`.

Comment: I've edited my question. And it's a school project so I have to do it with heroku and nodjs.

Comment: When I change it to just nodemon (without .cmd) than It's just nodemon:  not found.

Comment: "It's just nodemon: not found"—on Windows or on Heroku? In any case, I think your issue is something else. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use nodemon in "production", just node. Also in your `package.json` nodemon is declared as a dev dependency so it won't be installed on your heroku instance via npm anyway because I think `npm install --production` will be executed by heroku, so if you call it in your start script, it won't find it.

- edit your npm script "start" in package.json to `"start": "node index.js"` for example if index.js is your entry point. Since heroku will by default use the start script to launch your program.
- you can also add a script "dev" for you to use nodemon in your dev environment `"dev": "nodemon index.js"` for example if index.js is your entry point, then you can launch the app with nodemon by typing `npm run dev` in your terminal

Answer (score 1):

Nodemon is a development tool and shouldn't be used in production:

> Nodemon is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server. Perfect for development.

With Node.js projects, Heroku defaults to running your `start` script if it can't find a `Procfile`. Your `start` script is

```
"./node_modules/.bin/nodemon.cmd  ./bin/www"
```

It looks like you're *trying* to use Node.js instead of Nodemon by putting this in your `Procfile`:

```
web: node bin/www
```

But it looks like that file is named incorrectly. That capital `P` is important. Rename it to `Procfile`, e.g. by running `git mv procfile Procfile`. Then commit your change and redeploy.

Note that you can also use the [`heroku local`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local) command to run your application locally as Heroku would to make sure your `Procfile` is doing what it should.

Answer (score 0):

First, please follow the advice from other folks here: the `nodemon` should not be used for production. Spare it for dev machine and run the `node ./bin/www` directly on the prod.

E.g.,

```
// package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  }
```

Now to your issue.

The `nodemon` installs its executable into the `node_modules/.bin/`. It installs the executables for different OS:

- `nodemon` with the Bash syntax for the Linux,
- `nodemon.cmd` and `nodemon.ps1` for Windows (CMD and PowerShell).

Doing the `"start": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon.cmd ./bin/www"` is perfectly fine for Windows (it seems that you use it for development — I suppose it works :)

But for Linux servers (which Heroku provides in your case) the `nodemon.cmd` is not an option.

⚠️ If you *really want* to run it on Linux, do the `"start": "nodemon ./bin/www"`.
⚠️ But you should not do it on prod :)

It might happen that Linux does not set proper permissions to the `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon`:

```bash
$ ls -al node_modules/.bin/nodemon*
-rw-r--r-- 1 rom rom 312 Oct  7 21:39 node_modules/.bin/nodemon
-rw-r--r-- 1 rom rom 327 Oct  7 21:39 node_modules/.bin/nodemon.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 rom rom 813 Oct  7 21:39 node_modules/.bin/nodemon.ps1
```

It can be fixed by

```bash
$ chmod a+x node_modules/.bin/nodemon
```